# I want to delete the null elements in the array list which should decrease the size of the array

Tags: java, oop, junit5

This is my method to remove the number of null elements:

```
@Override
public void removeAt(int index) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = index; i < this.array.length -1; i++){
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        if(Arrays.toString(array).contains("null")) {
            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println("the number of null it has is " + count);
        }
        }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
      }
```

This is my test for the removeAt method:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("remove at index 0, then check size, went from 11 to 10")
void t8_removeAt() { 
    MutableArray<String> ma = new MutableArray<String>();
    
    //add 11 items to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        ma.append("number_" + i);
    }
    
    //delete element 0
    ma.removeAt(1);
    
    int actual = ma.size();
    int expected = 10;
    
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

This is the outcome:

```
the number of null it has is 1
the number of null it has is 2
the number of null it has is 3
the number of null it has is 4
the number of null it has is 5
the number of null it has is 6
the number of null it has is 7
the number of null it has is 8
the number of null it has is 9
the number of null it has is 10
the number of null it has is 11
the number of null it has is 12
the number of null it has is 13
the number of null it has is 14
the number of null it has is 15
the number of null it has is 16
the number of null it has is 17
the number of null it has is 18
[number_0, number_2, number_3, number_4, number_5, number_6, number_7, number_8, number_9, number_10, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not shrinking your inner `array` variable so its size is not changing.
Actually you are not even deleting elements from your list tou just shifting all elements to the right of null element which I think is not what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any statement in your code which can delete a `null` element from the array. A simple solution is to convert the given array into an `ArrayList` and then use an `Iterator` to iterate the `ArrayList` and delete the `null` elements. Once you are done with deleting `null` elements, convert the `ArrayList` back to an array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Original array
        String[] array = { "a", "b", null, "c", null, null, "d" };
        int originalSize = array.length;

        // Delete null elements
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
        Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.next() == null) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }

        // Convert list to array and assign it to original array reference
        array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("Number of null elements deleted: " + (originalSize - array.length));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[a, b, c, d]
Number of null elements deleted: 3
```